# How to convert "or" to SPARC assembly?

Tags: assembly, sparc

I'm trying to convert the following line to SPARC assembly (using negative logic):

```
if (i < a || i > b) {...}
```

But I've stuck on how to convert "or" to bitwise or in SPARC. And I couldn't find helpful documentations to convert this. Can someone help? Thank you.

(suppose `i` is in `$l0`, `a` is in `$l1`, and `b` is in `$l2` )

EDIT:

Here is what I have tried:

```
    cmp %l0, %l1 ! compare i with a
    bge end_if ! negative logic test to end if statement
    nop
    cmp %l0, %l2 ! compare i with b
    ble end_if ! negative logic test to end if statement
    nop
if:
    /*do something*/
end_if:
    /*statements*/
```

The more specific question is that how to use a "or" between two `cmp` instructions? This is getting very confusing to me when using negative logic.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)? And in the end, no matter what, it's just a question about comparing, testing and conditional jumping.

Comment: I suggest you "negate" the original condition first, and then build your assembly code from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code:

```
cmp %l0, %l1 ! compare i with a
bge end_if ! negative logic test to end if statement
nop
cmp %l0, %l2 ! compare i with b
ble end_if ! negative logic test to end if statement
nop
if:
    /*do something*/
end_if:
    /*statements*/
```

is an AND. both sub-conditions must be fulfilled, to reach the "do something" code.
(a bit of boolean logic perhaps helps explaining: `!(a ^ b) = !a v !b` note: the combining operation changes! )

for an OR, you have to use a different logic:

```
test condition1
jump_if_true doit
test condition2
jmp_if_true doit         ; *1) this branch and
jmp dont_doit            ; this jmp can be optimized

do_it:
   /* do if-part */
   jmp endif
dont_do_it
   /* do else-part */
endif:
```

now you could be optimized the last 2 jumps to just one

```
test condition1
jump_if_true doit
test condition2
jmp_if_not_true dont_doit         ; inverted to remove the 2nd jump

doit:
   /* do if-part */
   jmp endif
dont_doit
   /* do else-part */
endif:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that `if (cond1 || cond2) { ... }` is equivalent to

```
if (cond1) goto if_code
if (cond2) goto if_code

goto other_code

if_code:

   ...

other_code:
```

and that `if (cond1 && cond2) { ... }` is equivalent to

```
if ( ! cond1) goto other_code
if ( ! cond2) goto other_code

if_code:

   ...


other_code:
```

Your implementation matches the second pattern with `cond1 := i < a` and `cond2 := i > b` (beware of the negation).
So it is equivalent of `if (i < a && i > b){ ... }`.

The point is that in a disjunction `cond1 || cond2` if `cond1` is false it doesn't mean the disjunction is false, the other condition can be true.
The [absorption law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition) of the disjunction and conjunction operators is reflected on the implementation in terms of jumps.

In my code I left the short-circuit aspect of the evaluation unspecified. The conditions can be both evaluated ahead of time (no short-circuit) or only if needed (short-circuit).